# Calculating a due date based off two columns

Tags: calculated-column-formula, calculated-column, formula

I have an [assessment] and a [reassessment] column and I want to calculate the new reassessment due date.

If the [assessment] date is blank then I want the result to be blank.

If the [assessment] date is not blank and the [reassessment] date is blank then I want to add 3 years from the [assessment] date.

If the [reassessment] date is not blank then I want to add 6 years from the [assessment] date.

I need help. The formula below give me an error and this is where I am at.

```
=OR(IF(ISBLANK([Assessment]),(IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Reassessment])), "", DATE(YEAR([Assessment])+3,MONTH([Assessment]),DAY([Assessment])), DATE(YEAR([Assessment])+6,MONTH([Assessment]),DAY([Assessment]))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I resolved it.  =IF(ISBLANK([Assessment]), "",IF(ISBLANK([Reassessment]), DATE(YEAR([Assessment])+3,MONTH([Assessment]),DAY([Assessment])), DATE(YEAR([Assessment])+6,MONTH([Assessment]),DAY([Assessment]))                                                                                                                                                                                                                       thanks

Comment: You can answer your own question in below(answer) section.

Comment: I resolved it.  =IF(ISBLANK([Assessment]), "",IF(ISBLANK([Reassessment]), DATE(YEAR([Assessment])+3,MONTH([Assessment]),DAY([Assessment])), DATE(YEAR([Assessment])+6,MONTH([Assessment]),DAY([Assessment]))

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using below formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Assessment]), "",IF(ISBLANK([Reassessment]), DATE(YEAR([Assessment])+3,MONTH([Assessment]),DAY([Assessment])), DATE(YEAR([Assessment])+6,MONTH([Assessment]),DAY([Assessment]))
```